# Seeing some weird behavior with a nuneric field read from a file. What's the best way to clean it up?

Tags: python, pandas, integer, format

First thought was the data field type might be 'string', but it says 'integer'. How can two different values be coexisting (2 and 2.0)?

[image]

I used the 'int' function to the values, but it did not work.

Comment: Please clarify the question. I'm not sure what you're asking, and the screenshot doesn't seem to show much

Answer (score 0):

simply add this in your script:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
```

[image]